# Why is this lazy evaluation function not working in OCaml

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml, lazy-evaluation

I made this example up to better understand how lazy evaluation works in OCaml - using thonks.

```ml
let rec imp n = fun () -> imp(n*n);;
```

My understanding of lazy evaluation / thonks is that impl will
square an initial number as often as I'm calling
`imp ()`.

However this function `imp` raises the following error:

```
---
let rec imp n acc = fun()->(***imp (n\*acc)***);;

This expression has type int -> unit -> 'a
but an expression was expected of type 'a
The type variable 'a occurs inside int -> unit -> 'a
---
```

Comment: Your function has a recursive type; unless you expected that, that's a good hint that you made a mistake in your code. In particular, how do you think you'll be able to "see" the results of the operations made by this function? It will always return a copy of itself, never returning any result. Perhaps some numbers are squared internally, but you won't see them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The compiler is telling you that your function has a recursive type. You can work with recursive types if you supply `-rectypes` when you run `ocaml`:

```
$ ocaml -rectypes
    OCaml version 4.10.0

# let rec imp n = fun () -> imp(n*n);;
val imp : int -> (unit -> 'a as 'a) = <fun>
```

On the other hand I don't think your function works like you think. Or at least I don't see any way to find out what number it has recently calculated. You'll have to take it on faith that it is calculating larger and larger numbers, I guess.

Answer (score 3):

I would investigate the Seq module and use that.

Here's an example that demonstrates what you are trying to accomplish:

```
type func = Func of (unit -> int * func)

let rec incr_by_2 x =
  let ans = x + 2 in
  (ans, Func(fun () -> incr_by_2 ans))

let ans = incr_by_2 10

let () =
  match ans with
  | (d, Func f) -> print_endline(string_of_int d);
    match f() with
    | (d, Func f) -> print_endline(string_of_int d);
      match f() with
      | (d, _) -> print_endline(string_of_int d);
```

Please note the type constructor Func which is used to resolve the type problem in the function incr_by_2.

Here's an example using the Seq module's unfold function.

```
type func = Func of (unit -> int * func)

let rec incr_by_2 x =
  let ans = x + 2 in
  (ans, Func(fun () -> incr_by_2 ans))

let seq x =
  Seq.unfold
    (
      fun (d, Func f) ->
        if d < x
        then
          Some(d, f())
        else
          None
    )
    (incr_by_2 10)

let () =
  (seq 100) |> Seq.iter (Printf.printf "%d\n"); print_newline()
```